# WPF MVVM databing to datagrid not updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I want to display a list of notes from an object in a WPF DataGrid using MVVM

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid
        x:Name="NoteGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding NoteObj.Notes}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentNote}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" Binding="{Binding NoteText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type.Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The return-value of NoteObj.Notes is EntitySet.

ViewModel:

```
private NoteObject noteObj;
public NoteObject NoteObj
{
    get { return noteObj; }
    set { noteObj = value; OnPropertyChanged("NoteObj"); }
}

public void AddNote()
{
    var note = new Note
    {
        NoteText = "Note text",
        NoteType = 1
    };

    NoteObj.Notes.Add(note);
    DC.SubmitChanges();
    OnPropertyChanged("NoteObj");
}
```

When NoteObj is set the DataGrid is filled with notes but the AddNote-method doesn't wotk!
The new note is added to the database, but the DataGrid is never updated.

Is it a problem eith EntitySet or am I missing something in the XAML?

Comment: Try adding [presentationtracesources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx) and see if it gives you some hints in the output.

Comment: If I set the TraceLevel to "high" or "medium" the program crashes on SubmitChanges (row not found or something). No output!

Comment: which may indicate that there are problems with EF, not binding?

Comment: I use a LINQ to SQL datamodel auto-generated by VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work if `NoteObj.Notes` implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). You can achieve this by using the class [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Comment: Are you saying that I need to implement an ObservableCollection<Note> in my ViewModel, and "populate" this when the NoteObj is set?

Comment: "Pure" MVVM states that your entities have nothing to do with your UI, hence you would need to create a `NoteObjectViewModel` that contains a property `ObservableCollection<NoteViewModel> Notes`. Because if you don't, you run into problems just like this.

Comment: Somehow I can't get this right. Do you have a link to an article/tutorial that shows such an implementation? Can't find one with LINQ to SQL...